# (Hibernate) java.sql.SQLException: Field 'xxxx' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate is throwing the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'catVerb_id' doesn't have a default value
```

People say that the problem is with my PKs that haven't the AUTO_INCREMENT statement, however you can see that I've done this in my database and the issue continues. So, I brought my classes and my database implementations.

I think my problem is with the testing class... Somebody could show me how do I test this?

(Yes, some words are in Portuguese, but you can understand).

CategoriaVerbete

```
@Entity
@Table(name="verbete_categoria")
public class CategoriaVerbete implements Serializable{
    private long id;
    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private int serie;
    private Set<Verbete> verbetes = new HashSet<Verbete>();
    private Set<SignificadosVerbete> significados = new HashSet<SignificadosVerbete>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="catVerb_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", nullable = true) 
    public Set<Verbete> getVerbetes() {
        return verbetes;
    }
    public void setVerbetes(Set<Verbete> verbetes) {
        this.verbetes = verbetes;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", nullable = true)
    public Set<SignificadosVerbete> getSignificados() {
        return significados;
    }
    public void setSignificados(Set<SignificadosVerbete> significados) {
        this.significados = significados;
    }

}
```

Verbete

```
@Entity
@Table(name="verbete")
public class Verbete implements Serializable{
   ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public CategoriaVerbete getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public void setCategoria(CategoriaVerbete categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    ...
}
```

SignificadosVerbete

```
@Entity
@Table(name="verbete_significados")
public class SignificadosVerbete {
    ... 

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public CategoriaVerbete getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public void setCategoria(CategoriaVerbete categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

   ...

}
```

In the database...

```
CREATE TABLE verbete_categoria (
catVerb_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
catVerb_nome VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE,
catVerb_descricao MEDIUMTEXT,
catVerb_serie INT NOT NULL
);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

**UPDATE - PROBLEM SOLVED**

Well, I was expecting a triumphant soundtrack, but it's ok...

I just followed what this link says:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/fd26864d-cb41-49cf-b719-d89c6b072893/entry/como_criar_relacionamento_onetomany_com_hibernate?lang=en

I read that what is in that link isn't recommended by the Hibernate documentation, but I tried to follow the recomendations and passed one week treating errors. So, I hope this helps other people.

And thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Declare the annotations over the field id and not in the get method.

Comment: But I read that we can define annotations over the get methods or over the fields and that's not good to use both in the same class... Did I read wrong?

Comment: not sure, every reference I use... it is declared over the field, where did you read it?

Comment: This is an example: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Furthermore I have a class mapped in this way and it works fine...

Comment: @fmodos it's not bad declaring on getters.. this is not the problem,  do u have  the query u exec? by the way if u are using set u should override equals and hashcode methods

Comment: @nachokk, is there problem if I use List instead of Set? Maybe could this have relation with the problem?

Comment: i dont think that u  problem relies on that, is an advice i give u cause a set represents a set mathematically so to work properly u have to override equals and hashmethod to avoid repetitions the set use equals method.

Comment: Right, but can I use List instead of Set?

Comment: Yes u can.. the question is why u want to do that? Need specific order u may want allow repetitions?

Comment: Alright, now I understand the difference, thank you :)

Comment: The link with the solution does not work. (It has '...' in it.) Could you please provide a working link?

Comment: A working link is there :)

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is the `SignificadosVerbete` insertion that is causing the `cannot be null` issue (I would strongly suggest you to turn on sql trace to see which query is causing problems).

It is a common problem for bi-directional one-to-many relationships.  What you have is something like:

```
class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column("foo_id")
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL)
    @JoinColumn("foo_id")
    Set<Bar> bars;
}

class Bar {
    @Id
    @Column("bar_id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("foo_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    Foo foo;
}
```

This kind of mapping will cause the relationship to be owned by `Foo`, and this will create multiple `insert+update` statements:  When you are inserting a `Foo`, with 2 `Bar`s, what will happen is that it will first insert that `Foo`, and 2 Bar **without** the FK `foo_id`.  Then two updates will be issued for each `Bar` to update the correct `foo_id` in the `Bar` table.

Normally we do not map bi-directional `OneToMany` mappings this way, we do this instead:

```
class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column("foo_id")
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", cascade=ALL)
    Set<Bar> bars;
}

class Bar {
    @Id
    @Column("bar_id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn("foo_id")
    Foo foo;
}
```

By doing so, the relationship is owned by `Bar`, and when you are inserting as I described , you will be inserting 1 `Foo`, and 2 `Bar`s that already have the `foo_id` as part of insert.

That's how we normally do bi-directional relationships in Hibernate.

Comment: oops, have just read your update of that document, which seems suggesting what I was describing here.  Can't read Portuguese though :P

Comment: This is the answer that solved the problem for. Thanks a lot, Adrian! I didn't know these qualifiers (updatable, insertable) would affect the operations. I guess I need to educate myself deeply on how hiberante translates this to sql operations.

Comment: Glad it help (wow, almost 2 years.). Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I am not the op of the original question though :) I found your answer when researching my own problem. I upvoted, that's all I can do :)

Comment: @gruszczy lol sorry for my silliness, I thought you are the OP base on what you said  :P  I should have checked the name :P  Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the link provided. It worked following the link. As I understood, 
removing the below part did work for me.

Before:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

After:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id")
```

Comment: This worked for me as well, I am curious to know a solid answer why this works. I will update the answer with what I get in near future

Comment: Interestingly, having `insertable = false, updatable = false` doesn't seem to cause a problem with Fetch.LAZY...

Answer (score 1):

**java.sql.SQLException: Field 'xxxx' doesn't have a default value**

***( aka. indirect Fetch.LAZY load issue )***

I ran into this problem today.

Turned out to be a couple of issues in my situation.

The first thing I found that had to be fixed was that the List in question needed to be LAZY LOADED. And by LAZY LOADED I mean it has to be accessed from the database when the database "is in session". Now there is a little trick I found you have to do when you are dealing with Fetch.LAZY, **such that you need to (seemingly needlessly) call a method on the referenced object when you load it into the container**. It's not enough to just return the reference, even inside the session object.

For example, instead of just saying this:

```
public List<Apple> getApples(Kid kid) throws KidNotFoundException 
{
    log.info("getApples (service) called"); 
    kid = get(kid);
    List<Apple> list = kid.getApples();
    return list;
}
```

You have to add one more seemingly insignificant step. To trigger JPA's Lazy Load mechanism you need to call a method on the referenced object itself (and it only works when inside a JPA Transaction, whether direct or implied via a @Stateless tag). Till you do, JPA will be doing it's best not to load unnecessary objects into memory ( aka. *the whole idea behind Fetch.LAZY* ).

So in this case I call a method on the retrieved ( Fetch.LAZY designation ) object 'list' :

```
 list.size();
```

Any method on the object can be called to trigger JPA to load the object (or objects), in this case I just called the list.size() method was just so convenient, it doesn't look out of place as much as just calling a seemingly needless kid.getName(); from a professional standpoint of view. How I wish a good tutorial on Fetch.LAZY could have pointed all this out to me. Fodder for another book I guess ...

This forces JPA to actually load the referenced object from the database.

```
public List<Apple> getApples(Kid kid) throws KidNotFoundException 
{
    log.info("getApples (service) called"); 
    kid = get(kid);
    List<Apple> list = kid.getApples();
    list.size();
    return list;
}
```

That was the first issue generating the 'java.sql.SQLException: Field 'xxxx' doesn't have a default value' message in my case.

The second issue had to do with a improperly configured @ManyToMany relationship between the two tables. Today, it took about five minutes to set up what I thought was a many-to-many relationship from a previously created prototype I had. It took about six hours of hair pulling to get the kinks worked out. In any event, this is what I ended up doing to resolve my situation.

```
/**
 * "Buckets"
 * an Apple can be give to 0-to-n Kids ... 
 */

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="Buckets",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Apple_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Kid_id"))
private List<Kid> kids;

public List<Kid> getKids() {
    return kids;
}

public void setKids(List<Kid> kids) {
    this.kids = kids;
}
```

. . .

```
/**
 * a Kid can have 0-n Apples
 */

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="kids", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Apple> apples;
```

That and the fact that my original @ManyToMany setup was referencing the wrong table contributed to this error in my case. But the simple fixing of the LAZY LOAD situation resolved the 'java.sql.SQLException: Field 'xxxx' doesn't have a default value' problem immediately.

Perry

Ps.
After all day, I did learn some neat tricks hidden beneath JPA's rough exterior ( aka. surfing the web and reading docs on how to use @ManyToMany relationships efficiently ). Such that the above configuration will create a third database table dynamically that looks as good as though you created it by hand. It also enforces unique relationship between Kids and Apples as far as a one-to-one relationship is concerned. As well as create only one extra table in the database, instead of needing two identical tables in the database. In effect, in my case I had 2 tables before this @ManyToMany construct:

Kids
Apples

As a result of the @ManyTo@Many construct listed just as above I now have 3:

Kids
Apples
Buckets

Inside the Buckets table there are only two fields, Apple_id and Kid_id and what it important is that when I add an entry to both:

```
kids.add(apple);
apple.add(kids);
```

There is only ONE record in the Buckets table and not two! Which is very important if you are trying to use the List<> in place of a Set<>, ( aka. unique ).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the same column `catVerb_id` for `@JoinColumn` like

```
@JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", nullable = true)
```

try to change it to

```
@JoinColumn(name="catVerb_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

And it cannot be null because it's primary key in your case.

Comment: Try also: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: For OneToMany use OneToMany(targetEntity=, mappedBy=) instead of JoinColumn

Comment: I tried that, too, but nothing changes... Hey, can I put the test code here? Maybe I'm doing something wrong...